# Horizontally align radio_button_tag and label_tag in Rails with twitter bootstrap 2?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I can't seem to horizontally align the radio_button_tag with its label_tag. (Using HAML)

```
=radio_button_tag(:animal, "dog")
=label_tag(:animal, "Dog")
```

What classes do I assign to these two form helpers to make them sit next to each other like so:

```
O Dog
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `.form-inline` on the enclosing form tag usually fixes any vertical align issues I've encountered, though it might not be appropriate in all cases.

**Update**

Bootstrap now also has a couple of classes that you can apply to an enclosing block in order to line up checkboxes and radio buttons, respectively, with following text. From their documentation:

```
<label class="checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox" value="">
  Option one is this and that—be sure to include why it's great
</label>

<label class="radio">
  <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios1" value="option1" checked>
  Option one is this and that—be sure to include why it's great
</label>
<label class="radio">
  <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios2" value="option2">
  Option two can be something else and selecting it will deselect option one
</label>
```

It doesn't have to be a label - any block element should work.

See here: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/base-css.html#forms (section "Checkboxes and radios").

Answer (score 1):

For me, the various ways to display elements inline did not solve the problem. I realized the issue wasn't the display, but the content height for radio buttons (46px for some reason).

So, setting the height of the radio buttons to 'auto' solved the issue for me:

```
input[type='radio'] {
  height: auto;
 }
```